# How to index multiple web pages dynamically with google?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, sitemap, google-index

In my use case I would like index my web pages with google. My website is similar to stackoverflow.com model. User can create posts. I want that post to be indexed by google immediately.

I have a sitemap file placed in my server. How can index the new posts [when it gets created for the first time]?

Approach - I :

- Every time a new post is created, create the sitemap.xml for all the posts
- call the [google api](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/sitemaps/submit) and submit the sitmap.xml from javascript/backend.

Or is there any other way to do that?

I am fairly new to search engine indexing. Could someone help me with this?